# Submitting Form using Dynamic Text Link

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I'm at lost. What I wanted to do is, I want my website to allow the users to select a certain row(records) in my database and then redirect them to another webpage that will show them the full information about that certain record.. I don't know how could I connect those two web pages together using dynamic table/text..
Below is a portion of my code: ( This is the first webpage: )

```
mysql_select_db($database_rfq_portal, $rfq_portal);
$query_rfqrecord = "SELECT tblrfq.`RFQ_ID`, tblrfq.`Company_Name`, tblrfq.Service,
tblrfq.`Kind_of_Request`, tblrfq.Status, tblrfq.`Date` FROM tblrfq";
$rfqrecord = mysql_query($query_rfqrecord, $rfq_portal) or die(mysql_error());
$row_rfqrecord = mysql_fetch_assoc($rfqrecord);
$totalRows_rfqrecord = mysql_num_rows($rfqrecord);


<form id="viewform" name="viewform" method="get" action="ViewSpecificRFQ.php">
<table width="716" border="1" align="center" cellpadding="5">
<tr>
<td>RFQ ID</td>
<td>Company Name</td>
<td>Service</td>
<td>Kind of Request</td>
<td>Status</td>
<td>Date</td>
</tr>
<?php do { ?>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="ViewSpecificRFQ.phpRFQID=<?php echo $row_rfqrecord['RFQ_ID'];?>"><?php echo $row_rfqrecord['RFQ_ID']; ?></a></td>
    <td><a href="ViewSpecificRFQ.phpRFQID=<?php echo $row_rfqrecord['RFQ_ID'];?>"><?php echo $row_rfqrecord['Company_Name']; ?></a></td>
    <td><a href="ViewSpecificRFQ.phpRFQID=<?php echo $row_rfqrecord['RFQ_ID'];?>"><?php echo $row_rfqrecord['Service']; ?></a></td>
    <td><a href="ViewSpecificRFQ.phpRFQID=<?php echo $row_rfqrecord['RFQ_ID'];?>"><?php echo $row_rfqrecord['Kind_of_Request']; ?></a></td>
    <td><a href="ViewSpecificRFQ.phpRFQID=<?php echo $row_rfqrecord['RFQ_ID'];?>"><?php echo $row_rfqrecord['Status']; ?></a></td>
    <td><a href="ViewSpecificRFQ.phpRFQID=<?php echo $row_rfqrecord['RFQ_ID'];?>"><?php echo $row_rfqrecord['Date']; ?></a></td>
  </tr>
<?php } while ($row_rfqrecord = mysql_fetch_assoc($rfqrecord)); ?>
</table>
}
</form>
```

This is the webpage that will get the form..(portion of my code)

```
$RFQID = $_GET['RFQ_ID'];
mysql_select_db($database_rfq_portal, $rfq_portal);
$query_rfqrecord = "SELECT * FROM tblrfq WHERE $RFQID";

$rfqrecord = mysql_query($query_rfqrecord, $rfq_portal) or die(mysql_error());
$row_rfqrecord = mysql_fetch_assoc($rfqrecord);
$totalRows_rfqrecord = mysql_num_rows($rfqrecord);

mysql_select_db($database_rfq_portal, $rfq_portal);
$query_user = "SELECT tbluser.Username, tbluser.Password FROM tbluser";
$user = mysql_query($query_user, $rfq_portal) or die(mysql_error());
$row_user = mysql_fetch_assoc($user);
$totalRows_user = mysql_num_rows($user);



<table width="716" border="0" align="center">
<tr>
  <th colspan="2" scope="row">RFQ ID:</th>
  <td><?php echo $row_rfqrecord['RFQ_ID']; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th colspan="2" scope="row">Company Name:</th>
  <td width="511"><?php echo $row_rfqrecord['Company_Name']; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th width="101" rowspan="2" scope="row">Address:</th>
  <th width="90" scope="row">Site A:</th>
  <td><?php echo $row_rfqrecord['Address_A']; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th scope="row">Site B:</th>
  <td><?php echo $row_rfqrecord['Address_B']; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th colspan="2" scope="row">Contact Number:</th>
  <td><?php echo $row_rfqrecord['Contact_Number']; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th colspan="2" scope="row">Contact Person:</th>
  <td><?php echo $row_rfqrecord['Contact_Person']; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th colspan="2" scope="row">Service:</th>
  <td><?php echo $row_rfqrecord['Service']; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th colspan="2" scope="row">Bandwidth:</th>
  <td><?php echo $row_rfqrecord['Bandwidth']; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th colspan="2" scope="row">Telco:</th>
  <td><?php echo $row_rfqrecord['Telco']; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th colspan="2" scope="row">Account Manager:</th>
  <td><?php echo $row_rfqrecord['Account_Manager']; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th colspan="2" scope="row">Status:</th>
  <td><?php echo $row_rfqrecord['Status']; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th colspan="2" scope="row">Kind of Request:</th>
  <td><?php echo $row_rfqrecord['Kind_of_Request']; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th colspan="2" scope="row">Date:</th>
  <td><?php echo $row_rfqrecord['Date']; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th colspan="2" scope="row">Remarks:</th>
  <td><?php echo $row_rfqrecord['Remarks']; ?></td>
</tr>

</table>
</form>
```

this redirects the user to the next page but my problem is it keeps on showing the same record, which is the first record in my database.

Comment: In your form I don't see any way for your user to select the wanted row, you only have the submit button, am I missing something?

Comment: if you need multiple records to be selected put check-box in each column and also put submit button

Comment: @Frhay i added a link beside each row so that if the user clicks it, the user will be automatically direct to the next webpage. i didn't use submit button..(first webpage)

Comment: @Minesh uhm.. what i wanted to do is to select a single record then direct the user to the next webpage and display the full details(record) of what the user had chosen to view..

Comment: @KyoSohma You need to change the link to "ViewSpecificRFQ.php?RFQ_ID=<?php echo $row_rfqrecord['RFQ_ID'];?>" and on Edit page you only need to retrieve record for this GET parameter through WHERE condition in  SQL.

Comment: @Minesh i have already tried it but i got error message: " Notice: Undefined index: RFQ_ID in C:\wamp\www\RFQ_Portal\Web_Pages\ViewSpecificRFQ.php on line 37"..

Answer (score 0):

1- Consider page1.php is the first page that user selects a record and then in page2.php you show full detail.

for page1.php

you need to send some parameters like record id or any other key in order to be able to identify the record and select the detail in database.

for example:
Record 1 once user clicked on this link you have to do something like this in page2.php, remember our parameter is record_id

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['record_id'];
//we have to check it for validity
//if id is an integer (numbers) then simply we can check it
//if(!is_numeric($id)) { die("invalid id") }

// now the id is there
//lets build query
$query = "SELECT * from tablename where id= '$id' ";
?>
```

for your code it must be like this:
    //adding where clause
    $query_rfqrecord = "SELECT * FROM tblrfq where RFQ_ID = '$id' ";

```
$rfqrecord = mysql_query($query_rfqrecord, $rfq_portal) or die(mysql_error());
$row_rfqrecord = mysql_fetch_assoc($rfqrecord);
$totalRows_rfqrecord = mysql_num_rows($rfqrecord);
```

Comment: i have already tried $RFQID = $_POST['RFQ_ID'];
mysql_select_db($database_rfq_portal, $rfq_portal);
$query_rfqrecord = "SELECT * FROM tblrfq WHERE RFQ_ID = '$RFQID'";   but it gives me an error which is "Notice: Undefined index: RFQ_ID in C:\wamp\www\RFQ_Portal\Web_Pages\ViewSpecificRFQ.php on line 35"

Answer (score 0):

If you want your users to get to load a specific record when they click a specific row, you have to be sure you're redirecting them to a specific url. In your sample you have `<a href="ViewSpecificRFQ.php">` in your do-while, so every row in your table will have the same link and then the same destination page.

You probably want something like `<a href="ViewSpecificRFQ.php?recordId=<?php echo $row_rfqrecord['RFQ_ID'] ?>">` and then in your landing page the query will be performed against the key you will have in `$_GET['recordId']`.

EDIT: The do-while problem

You use a do-while, and so in your first iteration you have no record loaded, because the fetch instruction is located at the bottom of the code block, so you should change it to:

```
<?php
while ($row_rfqrecord = mysql_fetch_assoc($rfqrecord)) {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="ViewSpecificRFQ.php?recordId=<?php echo $row_rfqrecord['RFQ_ID'] ?>"><?php echo $row_rfqrecord['RFQ_ID']; ?></a></td>
        <td><a href="ViewSpecificRFQ.php?recordId=<?php echo $row_rfqrecord['RFQ_ID'] ?>"><?php echo $row_rfqrecord['Company_Name']; ?></a></td>
        <td><a href="ViewSpecificRFQ.php?recordId=<?php echo $row_rfqrecord['RFQ_ID'] ?>"><?php echo $row_rfqrecord['Service']; ?></a></td>
        <td><a href="ViewSpecificRFQ.php?recordId=<?php echo $row_rfqrecord['RFQ_ID'] ?>"><?php echo $row_rfqrecord['Kind_of_Request']; ?></a></td>
        <td><a href="ViewSpecificRFQ.php?recordId=<?php echo $row_rfqrecord['RFQ_ID'] ?>"><?php echo $row_rfqrecord['Status']; ?></a></td>
        <td><a href="ViewSpecificRFQ.php?recordId=<?php echo $row_rfqrecord['RFQ_ID'] ?>"><?php echo $row_rfqrecord['Date']; ?></a></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: It just means you actually have no RFQ_ID field in your record... :)

Comment: Oh now I see! You are using a do-while instead of a standard while, which means that in your first iteration you have actually no record! Give me a sec and I'll edit my answer to cover this problem too... :)

Comment: I tried that too.. but it gives me same error.. I really don't know what to do.. . i'm having a hard time solving this problem...i'm really sorry for bothering you :C but i really don't know how to fix this...

Comment: Ok... can you please take a var_dump of $row_rfqrecord and add it to your question so we can see what it actually contains? :)